# Emacs AucTeX; How to set C-c C-c default command?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I have set this in my .emacs file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 
      (lambda () 
        (setq TeX-command-default "LaTeX"))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 
      (lambda () 
        (setq TeX-command-default "LaTeX"))
```

I see that `C-c C-c` is bound to `TeX-command-master`, which calls `TeX-command-query`. But since my `(TeX-master-file)` is `"<none>"`, I expect the default command to be called, but keeps wanting to invoke "View" instead of "LaTeX".

Comment: Here is a link to alternative methods for using AUCTeX on OSX and Windows:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911  The compile command is separated from the view command, and is not dependent upon whether there has been a modification of the *.tex buffer to invoke one command or the other.

Comment: Thanks - but that's too much code for me to think through all the implications. Magnificent work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source for `TeX-command-query` you'll find that it checks the modification date of the `tex` (lines 4-9) and `bbl` (lines 10-19) files involved in your document. Unless those files are more recent than the output file and there is no *known* next command to be performed (lines 20-22) it will use the `"View"` command as default (line 23).

This behaviour is of course sensible because normally you don't want to recompile unless there are changes (modified `tex` files). Apart from "patching" the command [posted below, would not really recommend to use because it will not receive automatic updates ;-) ] there isn't really anything you can do.

If you decide to use the patched command, just put is somewhere in your init file **after** the original command has been loaded. You could for example wrap it into (replace `;; BODY` by code)

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex-buf" 
  '(progn
    ;; BODY
    ))
```

Here comes the patched command:

```lisp
(defun TeX-command-query (name)
  "Query the user for what TeX command to use."
  (let* ((default
       (cond ((if (string-equal name TeX-region)
              (TeX-check-files (concat name "." (TeX-output-extension))
                       (list name)
                       TeX-file-extensions)
            (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file)))
          TeX-command-default)
         ((and (memq major-mode '(doctex-mode latex-mode))
               ;; Want to know if bib file is newer than .bbl
               ;; We don't care whether the bib files are open in emacs
               (TeX-check-files (concat name ".bbl")
                    (mapcar 'car
                        (LaTeX-bibliography-list))
                    (append BibTeX-file-extensions
                        TeX-Biber-file-extensions)))
          ;; We should check for bst files here as well.
          (if LaTeX-using-Biber TeX-command-Biber TeX-command-BibTeX))
         ((TeX-process-get-variable name
                        'TeX-command-next
                        ;; HERE COMES THE PATCH
                        ;; was TeX-command-View
                        TeX-command-default)) 
                        ;; END OF PATCH
         (TeX-command-Show)))
         (completion-ignore-case t)
         (answer (or TeX-command-force
                     (completing-read
                      (concat "Command: (default " default ") ")
                      (TeX-mode-specific-command-list major-mode) nil t
                      nil 'TeX-command-history))))
    ;; If the answer is "latex" it will not be expanded to "LaTeX"
    (setq answer (car-safe (TeX-assoc answer TeX-command-list)))
    (if (and answer
             (not (string-equal answer "")))
        answer
      default)))
```

Comment: That makes sense. You can also modify the S-expression to replace that one expression? Or redefining is just easier?

Comment: @crippledlambda The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Change-a-defun.html) suggests to simply rewrite a function and evaluate it after loading the original function (thus overwriting it) is the way to go. However, one could also use something like [this](http://pastebin.com/tcNPHW5x) (stolen [from](https://github.com/thisirs/dotemacs)) to perform a _match replacement_. Personally, I think overwriting is the better solution (also simpler) because it ensures that the function itself is always working.

Comment: Wow, excellent references. I thought for very simple things like this, match replacement would be 1) shorter to replace and 2) in the event that the auctex package was updated, you could still get the benefits of the changes with this minor replacement. It's just an S-expression after all. But I was not aware the manual itself pushes the rewriting. That is good to know.